# How can i change dimension of picture with animate

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-animate

i have this function for 10 elements (images) and i need to click on each and grow abit then when i click on another to resize back to its original dimension and grow the last i've clicked.Heres some code:

**EDIT:** http://jsfiddle.net/MruMR/

```
var Answers = new Array();
var growing = true;

$(Answers).click(function(e){
    if(growing)
        $(e.target).animate({width:'400px'}, 500, function(){
        });
    else
        $(e.target).animate({width:'360px'}, 500, function(){
        });
    growing=!growing;
});

 for (var i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
        var elemente = document.getElementById("simbol" + i);
        Answers.push(elemente);
    }
```

Comment: Please let us know what you've tried, and if possible create a JSFiddle so we can work together on a solution.

Comment: You need to bind click event AFTER array is filled, not BEFORE!

Comment: @martincarlin87 Here OP is parsing an array of DOM nodes to a jquery object, that works even not better way of doing this for sure

Comment: i have added a fiddle

Comment: Maybe just avoid using a global variable: http://jsfiddle.net/MruMR/1/  But really, your code should be like this instead: `$('.simbol').click(function (e) {
    this.growing = !this.growing;
    $(e.target).animate({
        width: this.growing ? 180 : 155
    }, 500);
});` That's all you need here! http://jsfiddle.net/MruMR/2/

Comment: Yeah it looks better now but what i need is to resize back images when i click on another.First i click on image and is growing,then if i click on another,first image is resized back and new image is growing

Comment: @A.Wolff ah, see it now, don't think I've seen it done like that before. My mistake.

Comment: @martincarlin87 oh ya, i missed this part of your question...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should add a class to every simbol* element, then you would be able to bind handler to future elements by adding selector.

```
$(document).on('click', '.simbol', function() { ... });
```

To correctly grow/shrink elements, (IMHO) it should look something like this:

```
$('.simbol').not(e.target).animate({width:'360px'}, 500);//shrink all except the clicked one
$(e.target).animate({width:'400px'}, 500); //grow the clicked one
```

*However it would be better to do this with CSS3:*

```
//jQuery
$('.simbol').removeClass('grow');
$(e.target).addClass('grow');

/* CSS3 */
.simbol { width: 360px; transition: width 0.5s;}
.simbol.grow { width: 400px; }
```

Comment: This is even better version where you can unselect: http://jsfiddle.net/nothrem/MruMR/10/

Comment: Last fiddle is good to,but i'm gonna keep it with css3 .Thank you!